# Configuring the hostnameo f my mail/web server

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot

I've been working the last few days to configure a webserver on a VPS. I wanted for this VPS to handle my emails as well and so I installed Postfix and Dovecot.

After a big deal of configuring, I finally got it to work. However, there's something I dont quite understand.

My server's hostname is: server 
That makes my FQDN: server.mydomain.com

I would like clients to connect to mail.mydomain.com and smtp.mydomain.com but every tutorial i read says that you should use your hostname. Why can't I use `mail.mydomain.com`?.

I could of course rename the VPS's hostname to mail but it's a general server with other purposes as well.

I am running Debian 8 (jessie)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use mail.mydomain.com as hostname for your server, but as a best practice it's recommended to have your SMTP server to have the same FQDN as the reverse name. This is used by anti-spam systems to check if your server is properly configured and looks "legit" and is not just some pre-configured spam server with a fake/random name configured with it. Also see https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-reverse-dns-mismatch for further explanation and an example.

So, let's say the reverse hostname for your IP is `server.mydomain.com`, then make sure that `server.mydomain.com` is the primary name that your server uses when identifying itself. This does not stop you from creating a DNS alias `mail.mydomain.com` however. You can simply add a record to your DNS server like:

```
mail IN CNAME server.mydomain.com.
```

Then your clients can perfectly connect to `mail.mydomain.com`. The server will just respond with a header like:

> 220 server.mydomain.com Simple Mail Transfer Service Ready

Instead of identifying itself as `mail.mydomain.com`, but it will work without problems this way.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. In this case; Do I point my MX record to mail.mydomain.com or server.mydomain.com?

Comment: @Peter Both should work, but to be on the safe side I'd use server.mydomain.com so it matches the actual name of the server. An end-user shouldn't ever notice your MX record anyway, so there's no reason to use a "fancy" name there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do anything you want really as long as everything agrees with everything else.  Also on debian+postfix+dovecot+mysql backend,

/etc/hostname

```
  nodeidentifier
```

/etc/mailname

```
  mail.example.com
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   nodeidentifier
```

And in /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
myhostname = mail.example.com
mydestination = mail.example.com, nodeidentifier, localhost.localdomain, localhost
```

Reverse DNS points to mail.example.com.  I use mail.example.com as my incoming IMAP+SSL/TLS and outgoing SMTP in my clients via 587.